# Android getsupportedvideosizes returns null on emulator

Tags: android, camera

I have tried to get the supported video size as below in an emulator but it always return null.Why it is so?I have tried in 4.03.Thanks in advance

```
 Camera camera=Camera.open();
    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    supportedPicSizes = params.getSupportedVideoSizes();
    if (supportedPicSizes==null){
        Log.i("*****supportedVideoSize*****", "*****Null****"); 
    }
```

Comment: if my solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known Android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6271).

This still hasn't been fixed yet but the fact that it is on the bug tracking system probably means that Google has plans to see it through.

Comment: Isn't the question asking about "getSupportedVIDEOsizes"?? Why is it marked CORRECT for this answer which points to a bug related to getSupportedPreviewSizes??!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of the option by which you can get `Camera Preview Size` of the devices.

```
Camera camera=Camera.open();
android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
Size supportedPicSizes = params.getPreviewSize();
if (supportedPicSizes==null){
      Log.i("*****supportedVideoSize*****", "*****Null****"); 
}
else{
      Log.i("*****supportedVideoSize*****", "*****"+supportedPicSizes.height); 
      Log.i("*****supportedVideoSize*****", "*****"+supportedPicSizes.width); 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29) that a null return from this method means the device doesn't support different outputs for preview and video. In case of emulator, this situation must be prominent because an emulator doesn't have a physical camera and is generally not used for testing camera-related modules.

I would like to add that even though documentations have pointed this to be a normal case scenario, I'm still unable to find a proper alternative for devices suffering from this sickness. For instance, a Verizon variant of S3 return null for both "getSupportedVideoSizes()" and "getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()". Has anyone gone through a way around this issue?? A help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[answered also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22022062)

Sample code:

```
public List<Size> getSupportedVideoSizes(Camera camera) {
    if (camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes() != null) {
        return camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
    } else {
        // Video sizes may be null, which indicates that all the supported
        // preview sizes are supported for video recording.
        return camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }
}
```